# Format distance measurement as either kilometers or imperial miles, not metric miles

Tags: swift, formatting, foundation, measurement

I'm trying to format a `Measurement<UnitLength>` in either kilometers or miles, but not [Scandinavian miles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_mile) if the measurement is `> 10 km` and the locale is appropriate.

I want to use Swift and Foundation's new `.formatted` API but have not found the proper documentation to adjust the unit styling.

In short I want to present distance like the following examples:

- If shown in miles, show `3.5 mi`
- If shown in kilometers, show `7.1 km`
- If shown in kilometers but more than 10 km, show `13.5 km`, right now it shows (in Swedish locale) `1.4 mil`

I'm using the following code in SwiftUI to format the distance text

```
Text(distance.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)))
```

Here's some test code that I'm using to show the issue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale

    private let distance1 = Measurement(value: 7.04765, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)
    private let distance2 = Measurement(value: 13.4657, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(distance1.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road).locale(locale)))
            Text(distance2.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road).locale(locale)))
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            TestView() // Swedish
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "sv_SE"))
            TestView() // American English
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en_US"))
            TestView() // French
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr_FR"))
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This code generates the following:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the Scandinavian mile. I also didn't know there was a new `.formatted` API. Is that separate from the existing LengthFormatter class? And it's giving you Scandinavian miles when you're set for a Swedish locale?

Comment: @DuncanC The new `.formatted` API isn't yet documented very well, but you can see a video from WWDC 21 of it at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/ - skip forward to 14:30.

Comment: @DuncanC I added sample code in my question but I'd not like to change the user's locale to remove the "Scandinavian mil(e)" which is why I ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.general` instead of `.road` will give you kilometres or miles according to locale. `.asProvided` will give you the units defined on the original measurement.

I think `.general` gets you closest to what you want, though it may end up giving you metres or yards for non-kilometre ranged values.